# How to attach logger from a separate module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I've imported a python module, apex (from NVIDIA), which uses its own logger. Unfortunately those logged messages are not getting caught by my main logger, which also writes to a file.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # my main logger
```

what I need to do is (somehow) run logging.getLogger("apex.amp") so that I can attach the apex logger to my main logger, and catch the corresponding warnings, etc.

How do I combine the loggers?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign your logger to the `'apex.amp'` key of the `loggerDict` dict of the `manager` object:

```
logging.manager.loggerDict['apex.amp'] = logger
```